# Let $G$ be a subgroup of $E(2)$ and suppose that $T$ is the translation subgroup of $G$. Prove that the point group of $G$ is isomorphic to $G/T$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group, stabilizer

$E(n) = \{(A,x):A \in O(n) \text{ and } \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$, where $O(n)$ is the group of real orthogonal $n \times n$ matrices

The point group associated to $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a subgroup $G \subset E(n)$ is the stabalizer of $p$ in $G$. The stabilizer of $p$ in $G$ is the group of elements that fix $p$, i.e. $gx=x, \forall g \in G$. So I think the point group of $G$ associated to $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the subgroup of elements $(A,b)$ such that,
\begin{equation}
        Ap + b = p
\end{equation}
Would this consist of elements of the form $(A,0)$ where $A$ is a rotation matrix by $2 \pi n$?

And then I think the translation subgroup $T$ is the subgroup of $G$ with elements of the form $(I,x)$. Wouldn't this make $G/T$ the set of matrices $(A,0)$ (not necessarily rotation matrices)?

How would you come up with a bijection between these two?

Comment: Please remind us what $E(n)$ is.

Comment: $E(n) = \{(A,x):A \in O(n) \text{ and } \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$, where $O(n)$ is the group of real orthogonal $n \times n$ matrices

Comment: $E(n)={\rm Isom}(\Bbb R^n)$ is the isometry group of $\Bbb R^n$. The translation subgroup is a normal subgroup. For more details see [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~tkc/GeometryandGroups/GeometryandGroups.pdf) under isometry group of Euclidean space.